# Loading a trained HDF5 model into Rust to make predictions

Tags: tensorflow, rust, hdf5

I trained a model to recognize digits using the MNIST dataset.  The model has been trained in Python using TensorFlow and Keras with the output saved into a HDF5 file I named "sample_mnist.h5".

I would like to load the trained model from the HDF5 file into Rust to make predictions.

In Python, I could generate the model from the HDF5 and make predictions with the code:

```py
model = keras.models.load_model("./sample_mnist.h5")
model.precict(test_input)  # assumes test_input is the correct input type for the model
```

What is a Rust equivalent of this Python snippet?

Answer (score 4):

First off, you'll want to save the model in **.pb** format, not **.hdf5**, to port it over to Rust, as this format saves **everything** about the execution graph of the model necessary to reconstruct it outside of Python. There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/rust/pull/286/files) from user [justnoxx](https://github.com/justnoxx) on the TensorFlow Rust repo that shows how to do this for a simple model. The gist is that given some model in Python ...

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', name="test_in", input_dim=5)) # Named input
classifier.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="test_out")) # Named output

classifier.compile(optimizer ='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.fit([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]], [[1]], batch_size=1, epochs=1);

classifier.save('examples/keras_single_input_saved_model', save_format='tf')
```

and our named input "test_in" and output "test_out" and their expected sizes, we can apply the saved model in Rust ...

```rust
use tensorflow::{Graph, SavedModelBundle, SessionOptions, SessionRunArgs, Tensor};

fn main() {

    // In this file test_in_input is being used while in the python script,
    // that generates the saved model from Keras model it has a name "test_in".
    // For multiple inputs _input is not being appended to signature input parameter name.
    let signature_input_parameter_name = "test_in_input";
    let signature_output_parameter_name = "test_out";

    // Initialize save_dir, input tensor, and an empty graph
    let save_dir =
        "examples/keras_single_input_saved_model";
    let tensor: Tensor<f32> = Tensor::new(&[1, 5])
        .with_values(&[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
        .expect("Can't create tensor");
    let mut graph = Graph::new();

    // Load saved model bundle (session state + meta_graph data)
    let bundle = 
        SavedModelBundle::load(&SessionOptions::new(), &["serve"], &mut graph, save_dir)
        .expect("Can't load saved model");

    // Get the session from the loaded model bundle
    let session = &bundle.session;

    // Get signature metadata from the model bundle
    let signature = bundle
        .meta_graph_def()
        .get_signature("serving_default")
        .unwrap();

    // Get input/output info
    let input_info = signature.get_input(signature_input_parameter_name).unwrap();
    let output_info = signature
        .get_output(signature_output_parameter_name)
        .unwrap();

    // Get input/output ops from graph
    let input_op = graph
        .operation_by_name_required(&input_info.name().name)
        .unwrap();
    let output_op = graph
        .operation_by_name_required(&output_info.name().name)
        .unwrap();
    
    // Manages inputs and outputs for the execution of the graph
    let mut args = SessionRunArgs::new();
    args.add_feed(&input_op, 0, &tensor); // Add any inputs

    let out = args.request_fetch(&output_op, 0); // Request outputs

    // Run model
    session.run(&mut args) // Pass to session to run
        .expect("Error occurred during calculations");

    // Fetch outputs after graph execution
    let out_res: f32 = args.fetch(out).unwrap()[0];

    println!("Results: {:?}", out_res);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?